# C# Have problems generating random 2d array from smaller arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, random

I am trying to generate a random 2D array, from a number of smaller arrays. I plan to use it some day to generate a random game map.

Each smaller array is called "Island". Each of them is manually predefined.

```
            char[,] Island1 = new char[,]
            {
                {'A', 'A', 'A'},
                {'A','B','A'},
                {'A','A','A'}    
            };

            char[,] Island2 = new char[,]
            {
                {'C', 'C'},
                {'C','C'}    
            };   

            char[,] Island3 = new char[,]
            {
                {'D', 'D', 'D'},
                {'D','D','D'},
                {'D','D','D'}    
            };
```

I am trying to generate a larger array, with all smaller ones inside, placed randomly.

What's important, is that smaller arrays shouldn't overlap each other.

```
    public static Boolean CanPlaceIsland(int StartX, int StartY, Island thisIsland)
    {
        Boolean Answer = true;

        for (int i = StartX; i<StartX+thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(0);i++)
        {
            for (int j = StartX; j<StartY+thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(1);j++)
            {
                    if (WorldMap[i,j].Terrain!='.')
                        Answer = false;
            }
        }

        return Answer;
    }
```

I am trying to go through each island, one by one, and only add new one, if it doesn't overlap non-empty squares.

**Here's updated method for filling the map with islands (previous version could cause infinite loop).**

```
    public static void CreateEmptyMap()
    {
        WorldMap = new Cell[WorldX, WorldY];

        for (int i=0; i<WorldX; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<WorldY; j++)
                WorldMap[i,j] = new Cell('.');                    
    }


    public static void FillMap()
    {
        int IslandsPlaced=0;

        foreach(Island thisIsland in IslandsList)
        {
                Boolean check = false;

                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;

                    Random w = rnd;

                    int SideA = thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(0);
                    int SideB = thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(1);

                    int WorldSideA = WorldMap.GetLength(0);
                    int WorldSideB = WorldMap.GetLength(1);                        

                    x = w.Next(2, WorldSideA-SideA-1);
                    y = w.Next(2,WorldSideB-SideB-1);

                    check = CanPlaceIsland(x,y,thisIsland);                           

                if (check==true)
                {
                    PlaceIsland(x,y,thisIsland);                              
                    IslandsPlaced++;
                }    
        }   

        if (IslandsPlaced!=IslandsList.Count())
        {
            CreateEmptyMap();
            FillMap();
        }
    }
```

The placing:

```
    public static void PlaceIsland(int x, int y, Island thisIsland)
    {
        int SideA = thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(0);
        int SideB = thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(1);

            for (int i=0; i<SideA;i++)
            {
               for (int j=0; j<SideB;j++) 
               {
                   WorldMap[x+i,y+j] = thisIsland.CellArray[i,j];
               }
            }  
    }
```

However, sometimes islands still overlap, and I can't find why.

```
 ..........
 ..........
 ..........
 ..........
 ....AAA...
 ..DDDBA...
 ..DDDAA...
 ..DDD.....
 ..........
 ..........
```

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Your code suggests that you are placing the island regardless of whether `check` is true _or_ false...

Comment: Shouldn't this be StartY :  (int j = StartX; j<StartY+thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(1);j++) ?  Also the lenght needs to be different for x direction (short length) and  y direction (long length).

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. You are referencing a class Island which apparently has a property `CellArray`, but your sample islands are apparently just 2-Dimensional char arrays. You also don't show code about how the code comes together in one program. But please don't post the whole code: Simplify the program down to just the pieces that are causing you trouble, for example get rid of the random element and place the islands manually in ways that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Stuart Yes, that can be the case. I expected something like that, a small but painful mistake.

Comment: ...so what happens when you `if (check) { PlaceIsland(); }` ?

Comment: @clcto Sorry, I am no longer near computer, writing from phone. That's not the case, for now each Island is an array of Cell class, and in this case, Cell class has only a char variable. So arrays of chars are converted correctly, I checked this.

Comment: @Stuart As I said in one comment earlier, I can't check it now. Will check and reply tomorrow.

Comment: @Stuart how would it exit the `while` loop if `check` is `false`?  The code does seem to result in an infinite loop if an island can't be placed.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Surely `CanPlaceIsland` willl return false, if your logic is correct and it cannot place an island?

Comment: the while condition means it won't exit until the island can be placed.  if there is no valid place for the island to go then the while loop will continue forever.

Comment: The correct answer is below, it was a mistype. As for infinite loop - I already made the code to make Worldmap array size depending on the quantity and sizes of sub-arrays, and also added some free space, to make sure all islands can be placed. If someone wants, I can add a method for generating size to my original post. EDIT: Actually I'll add something to remove all islands if the loop is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is in `CanPlaceIsland`:

```
for (int j = StartX; //error here! 
     j < StartY + thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(1); 
     j++) { ... }
```

Should be:

```
for (int j = StartY; 
     j < StartY + thisIsland.CellArray.GetLength(1); 
     j++) { ... }
```

Looks like a typical copy and paste bug...

Apart from that, if your maps are rather crowded, you risk entering an infinite loop if there is no solution for a given island.

Computing if one or more valid solutions exist and if the combination you are currently in is one of them can be expensive and somewhat tricky so, unless you really have to deal with crowded maps where a solution must be given, I'd bale out after a predetermined number of failed attempts placing an island; you might get false negatives once in a while but its probably something you can live with.

Comment: This answer is the correct one. It was mistype in the end. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to do something that will reset the map if loop is stuck.

Comment: Updated OP with new loop that seems not to stuck.

Comment: @EvgenieT No, that’s not good enough. If there is no solution you will be infinitely retrying to find a valid map. Also, the way you are doing thingd implies unnecessary work. Don’t retry the whole map when you fail to place one island, retry the island that failed and if you can’t find a solution in a predetermined number of times either reset the whole map or simply give up. Resetting the map should also have a maximum number of tries after which you should also give up.